# How to convert GenericRecord to a json string corresponding to the schema given in Avro

Tags: java, avro, spark-avro, jackson-dataformat-avro

I have a requirement where i need to store the data in json format in AWS S3, we are currently hitting an enpoint which gives List[GenericRecord], and that needs to be stored in Json format, can any one share a sample code for achieving this. I am unable to deserialize GenericRecord to Json string, and even ObjectMapper writeValueAsString method is also not working on it

Comment: `I am unable to deserialize GenericRecord to Json string` - can you provide us a piece of code that you have by now trying to do this?

Comment: @pradeep.D.s I am trying to do the same and found this example https://gist.github.com/hammer/76996fb8426a0ada233e

I you have written something similar can you please share your solution?